# What kind of icon should I deploy with my Android 1.x and 2.x application?

Tags: android, user-interface

The thing is this, in Android 1.5 and 1.6 we had the [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html). In this guide there are specifications for application icons. Every application should conform to this. However, in recent Android versions (2.0 and 2.1) icons have changed from the old to this new flat 2D style. Every icon in Nexus One has this style, so not even Google is conforming to the [guideline](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html). To see the differences between high and low density icons see this [image](http://smarterware.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/android21-menucube.png) and compare Evernote icon with the rest.

I've been able to use different icons by using two directories with different icons: `drawables-hdpi/icon.png` and `drawables/icon.png`, BUT not every Android 2.x is going to be HDPI and not every 1.x Android device is going to be low pixel density. So the question is:

Should I deploy different icons for different Android platform version within my apk file? and if I should, How do I do it?

Comment: As a sidenote, Google has been saying they'd update the Icon Design Guidelines for a few months now but haven't...  sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are additional resource identifiers you can use to target the particular Android version running on a device.

For example, you could use `drawable-v3` for Android 1.5 and 1.6, and `drawable-v5` for Android 2.0 and above (or rather `drawable-ldpi-v5`, `drawable-mdpi-v5` and `drawable-hdpi-v5` in practice).

You need to have the three icons for the three different screen densities anyway (otherwise, it doesn't look so good after scaling), so adding an extra directory/icon for Android 1.5 isn't so bad.

Or you could just ditch the Android 1.5 folder and let it have a "flat" icon — I'm sure users wouldn't be particularly bothered.